# MAC address order changed after windows 10 update

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, mac-address

I have a program that read the mac address with [networkadapterconfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapterconfiguration)(using the **MACAddress property**)

I was reading all the mac address well and good, but for some reason after the update to build 1803, I was getting the mac address shifted

[image]

on the midlle column are the mac on version 1709 and on the rightmost columns you can see macs after the update to 1803

any idea on can I ensure that I always read them in the same order, or somehow granted to read them in a specific order

here's my code

```
public static List<string> WMISearcher(string WMIClassName, string 
searchParams, bool win32_Prefix = true, string rootNamespace = "")
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();

   var searcherData = getSearcherData(WMIClassName, searchParams, win32_Prefix, rootNamespace);
   foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcherData)
   {
       foreach (PropertyData data in obj.Properties)
           if (data.Value != null)
               result.Add(data.Value.ToString());

   }

   return result;


 }


 private static ManagementObjectCollection getSearcherData(string WMIClassName, string searchParams, bool win32_Prefix = true, string rootNamespace = "")
       {
           string prefix = "Win32_";
           string rootPrefix = @"root\";
           if (!win32_Prefix)
               prefix = String.Empty;

           if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(rootNamespace))
               rootNamespace = rootPrefix + rootNamespace;
           else
               rootNamespace = rootPrefix + "cimv2";

           string searchQuery = String.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1}", searchParams, prefix + WMIClassName);
           using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                   new ManagementObjectSearcher(rootNamespace, searchQuery))
           {
               //  Console.WriteLine("{0}", WMIName);
               return searcher.Get();
           }
       }
```

and I use the above function like this

```
 var MACAddressResult = WMIUtils.WMISearcher("NetworkAdapterConfiguration", "MACAddress");
```

Comment: Would it be possible to just sort the list?

Comment: you have different set of adaptors. I assume some of them are virtual. Maybe they got recreated?

Comment: @Steve yes I do have adapters(3 of them), and I don't know(or rather don't know how to check) if those recreated

Comment: @JLe i will check that

Comment: The MAC is a response from a PING (ARP Request) and the time of the responses are not always going to be the same.  To always get the same order you will need to sort.

Comment: Did the documentation ever make any *promises* about any assumptions you could safely make about output order? I doubt it.

Comment: @styx when the adapter gets recreated its considered to be a totally different one than the one before. Has absolutely no relation with the old one besides maybe the same name (not guaranteed either). So your best bet is to get more info and try to correlate them

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use [ORMi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ORMi/) and sort the list as you wish:

Lazy option:

```
var adapters = helper.Query("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration").ToList();
```

Strong typed option:

1) Declare your model (This is an example, you can add or remove whatever property you need):

```
[WMIClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")]
public class NetworkAdapterConfiguration
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public uint IPConnectionMetric { get; set; }

    public UInt32 InterfaceIndex { get; set; }

    public string WINSScopeID { get; set; }
}
```

2) Query and order by:

```
List<NetworkAdapterConfiguration> interfaces = helper.Query<NetworkAdapterConfiguration>().OrderBy(n=>n.Description).ToList();
```

That way you have a list you can sort by whatever you want (in this case `Description`). Visit the project repository for more reference.

Comment: how does it differ from "manually" calling the WMI and sorting it?

Comment: @styx well in first place you write much less code for getting what you need. They you got strong typed objeta to work with. Much better, cleaner and easy IMHO.